# Get rid of classes from views root container

Tags: views, 7

Looking for a way to clear all unnecessary in terms of semantic classes from top-level div for a view:

```
<div class="view view-comments-count view-id-comments_count view-display-id-entity_view_2 view-dom-id-f2370f55bf76844fef6e17764e8a5058">
      <div class="view-content">
        ROWS
    </div>
</div>
```

want to become:

```
<div class="view">
      <div class="view-content">
        ROWS
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews) and [Fences](https://www.drupal.org/project/fences) but they all deal only with view content (field or rows) but not with the top-level div config.

I know that some bits can be changed with `views-view.tpl.php` however you can only clear all classes from it but I want to use css class from Views configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [template_preprocess_views_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7) function and remove needles classes from  `$vars['classes_array']` array.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'my_view') {
    $vars['classes_array'] = array('view', $vars['css_class']);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case I wouldn't be able to set the class in a views setting (called CSS class).

Comment: You can add this class in array in template_preprocess_views_view

Comment: How do I find this class in an array? I want the class to be set from Views UI.

Comment: $css_class = $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class');
  if (!empty($css_class)) {
    $vars['css_class'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]/', '-', $css_class);
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $vars['css_class'];
  }

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get where I need to put this code. $view is undefined in the module.

Comment: $view = $vars['view'];
$css_class = $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class');
  if (!empty($css_class)) {
    $vars['css_class'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]/', '-', $css_class);
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $vars['css_class'];
  }

Comment: It is something I was looking for. Could you update your post with the following code so I can choose it as an answer:
  `$view = $vars['view'];

  $css_class = $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class');

  if (!empty($css_class)) {
   $vars['css_class'] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9- ]/', '-', $css_class);
   $vars['classes_array'] = array('view');
   $vars['classes_array'][] = $vars['css_class'];
  }`

Could you also tell why there is: `$css_class = $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class');`? Could we just use `$vars['css_class']`. It is there in $vars when hook is fired.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You are right we do not need to use $css_class = $view->display_handler->get_option('css_class'); because $vars['css_class'] is already added in https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/7

Comment: Great! Sorry I brought you 666 points ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26107/discussion-between-andrew-and-valera-tumash).